# In grails 3 command object get field to populate list of domain

Tags: grails, grails3

I need to store a list of domains and for that I have used a list in the command-object in the controller.
But when I try to get the domain object from argument (command-object)list it gives me IndexOutOfBound error.

I also tried to lazy list concept with command object. Still, the command object list is not populated.

```
    class CategoryItems{ // command object class
       List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>()
    }

   class ItemController{
     def save(CategoryItems categoryItems){
            service.save(categoryItems.get(0)) // getting indexOutOfBound 
                                               //Exception
          }
     }
```

How can I populate the List of command-objects ?

Comment: You described a problem but to get an answer it would be better if you also would ask a question.

Comment: How it's came that you tried to get(0) from the object? I think you should update it to service.save(categoryItems) or if you want to save item: service.save(categoryItems.items?.getAt(0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a command object as an argument to a controller action, you receive an instance of that command object.

In your case, it's an instance of the command object you have created and not a list of command objects. Since you have created a list of Items, you can save each items as such

```
categoryItems.items.each{
   service.save(it)
}

// or
categoryItems.items.each{ Item item ->
   service.save(item )
}
```